ROS2 control manger not available with fast DDS Discovery server
I have a problem with ros2 control when launching with Fast DDS Discovery Server. During the launch it shows that the control manager received robot description file as you can see here:
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1713447422.403860164] [robot1.controller_manager]: Received robot description file.

and also the node is shown in the rqt graph. However, the individual controllers such as joint_state_broadcaster are waiting for the control manager but cannot find it.
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1713447423.620905592] [robot1.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/robot1/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1713447431.668242084] [robot1.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available

Without Fast DDS Discovery Server everything works perfectly and all controllers work.
Now my question is if there is a solution for this?

I had the same problem. In my setup the problem was, that services didn't work with the discovery server. I haven't managed to fix that. Can you check if other services work?

Okay, that's good to know that I'm not the only one with this problem. So I see two possibilities here: 1) Docker Swarm 2) Cyclone DDS also has a mode where you can set the ip addresses. But I would have to try and test that myself, but I won't get around to it until next week.

I found out it is a bug: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1182
According to the github repo, the bug is already being worked on.
